# Vagrant, difference between docroot and path?

Tags: apache, vagrant, puphpet

I am kind of new to vagrant and all of this (used xampp untill now for learning). Anyway, I am currently using puphpet to setup my boxes, and its working great.

But, I now have a question about config.yaml file. Under vhosts, what is the difference between docroot, and directories/avd_8.../path?

Do they have to be the same?

Docroot is the root folder of my whole project? Its where I have my index.php? If so, how is path different from it then?

Also, if I want to keep some files out of public directory, do I just keep them one directory back from docroot?

Thanks.

Edit: here is part of my config.yaml file that contains those 2 settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AawqF.jpg